# wxPython install dependencies issues

Tags: command-line, python, compatibility, source-packages, wxpython

First off, Hey ya'll, I'm new. Thanks for being here. I'm a casual Linux user that picked up Ubuntu as an alternative to Windows 10 while in college learning R. Currently I'm trying to run an OBD-II program based in Python on an old Laptop I have running Ubuntu 18.04. I'm attempting to sort through the requisites for a program called PyOBD and I've hit a snag on one.

I need to install wxPython v2.4 specifically for this program. It was written in the early 2000s and there is no support for it. I am not having much luck with the install. I have the tarball. I've got it extracted and when I go to run the ./configure file it fails and pops up:

> configure: warning: system tiff library not found, will use built-in instead
>   checking for GTK+ version... 
>   checking for gtk-config... no
>   checking for GTK - version >= 1.2.7... no
>   *** The gtk-config script installed by GTK could not be found**
>    If GTK was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
>    **your path, or set the GTK_CONFIG environment variable to the**
>    full path to gtk-config.
>   checking for gtk-config... (cached) no
>   checking for GTK - version >= 1.2.3... no
>    **The gtk-config script installed by GTK could not be found**
>    If GTK was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
>    **your path, or set the GTK_CONFIG environment variable to the
>   *** full path to gtk-config.
>   configure: error: 
>   Please check that gtk-config is in path, the directory
>   where GTK+ libraries are installed (returned by
>   'gtk-config --libs' command) is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or
>   equivalent variable and GTK+ is version 1.2.3 or above.

Obviously, this has something to do with GTK, but my novice brain does not comprehend what it's being told. I understand there are 3 versions of GTK and evidently this particular program is looking for one greater than v1.2 (which I am all but positive should already be present in 18.04?) but there is an issue with the filepath. I've tried and failed to update GTK, build and older version (albeit probably doing something wrong), etc. What do?

P.S. Thanks for reading my novel. TLDR is I'm a noob and I'm in way over my head apparently.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, pictures are harder to read, and we cannot copy/paste details from a picture to look up answers for you.  GTK1 is way past EOL, as is GTK2; GTK3 is where things are currently with new development in GTK4 progressing.  GTK was originally the GIMP Toolkit, GNOME started using it so it became GTK+, recently the + was dropped (it's GIMP & GNOME Toolkit but usually just referred to as GTK)  18.04 uses GTK3, and has no GTK1 (GTK3 having capacity only for some legacy GTK2)

Comment: picture replaced with text for ease of use, my bad. Am I understanding you correctly that running a GTK1 program may not be an option at this point? Or, should I look to install GTK1.xx?

Comment: What exact version of `wxPython v2.4` are you trying to build, and where did you obtain it? At least for `wxPythonSrc-2.4.2.4`, it appears to provide experimental support for GTK2 by using `./configure --enable-gtk2` (you will of course need `libgtk2.0-dev`)